# I get this error code in VS: 0x80070002 c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

When i try to run a code with the function "strtok" in it i get the error code 0x80070002. I included cstring, cctype, string.h and i also tried using /DEBUG FULL in Properties - Linker - Debugging, like a few other posts said but it still doesn't work. Any clues why VS doesn't work with strtok? I also tried reinstalling VS and running a simple code like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[100], * p;
    cin.getline(s, 100);
    p = strtok(s, " ");
    cout << p;
    return 0;
}
```

The desired behaviour would be to show me the first word of s. Even when i try to run the code at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok i get the same error.

Comment: I guess that would be `strtok`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to meet your needs;

1. Add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in `Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions`.
2. Use [strtok_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l?view=msvc-160) instead of `strtok`:

   ```
    int main()
    {

        char *buf;
        char s[100], *p;
        cin.getline(s, 100);
        p = strtok_s(s, " ", &buf);
        cout << p;
        return 0; 
    }
   ```